# How to import category and add parent relation conditionally from csv using cypher in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to create a **Category** entity from csv and also create a **PARENT** relation to the  category if the parent_id in the csv is not empty or 0

Sample csv is as follows

```
cid,category_name,parent_id
1,Category1,0
2,Category1,1
3,Category3,1
4,Category4,3
```

And the Graph entity will be like

```
 Category{cid,name}
```

If parent category is not empty in csv then add relation

```
(cat:Cateogry)-[:PARENT]->(pcat:Category)
```

Below is the cypher code I written and its importing the category but not adding the **PARENT** relation

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://pathto/category.csv" AS csvLine 
 FIELDTERMINATOR ','
MERGE (cat:Category {cid: toInt(csvLine.cid), name:csvLine.category_name})
WITH csvLine, cat
WHERE csvLine.parent_id <> 0
MATCH (pc:Category{cid:csvLine.parent_id}) 
MERGE (cat)-[:PARENT]->(pc)
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the potential problem in this query and how can I debug the same ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you didn't use `toInt` in the match.

In general when the order of rows is not parent-first, you can use MERGE in both places.

neo4j-community-2.1.5/bin/neo4j-shell -path test.db -file categories.cql

```
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 4
Relationships created: 3
Properties set: 8
Labels added: 4
2894 ms
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n                               | pc                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[1]{cid:2,name:"Category1"} | Node[0]{cid:1,name:"Category1"} |
| Node[2]{cid:3,name:"Category3"} | Node[0]{cid:1,name:"Category1"} |
| Node[3]{cid:4,name:"Category4"} | Node[2]{cid:3,name:"Category3"} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows
137 ms
```

wuqour:categories mh$ cat categories.cql

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/mh/support/categories/categories.csv" AS csvLine 
 FIELDTERMINATOR ','
MERGE (cat:Category {cid: toInt(csvLine.cid)}) 
SET cat.name=csvLine.category_name
WITH csvLine, cat, toInt(csvLine.parent_id) as parent
WHERE parent <> 0
MERGE (pc:Category{cid:parent}) 
MERGE (cat)-[:PARENT]->(pc);

match (n:Category)-[r:PARENT]->(pc)
return n,pc;
```